# jpa unidirectional One-to-Many with a Collection of Abstract type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I'm having an issue with JPA. Basically, what I have is an entity with a list of an abstract type and I need each element of the list to be persisted in its corresponding table with a foreign key (to relate to the entity). Here is the code:

```
@Entity(name = "entity")
public class Entity{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private BigInteger id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private List<AbstractType> types;
}
```

Abstract type:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractType{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private BigInteger id;

private String someProp;

@Column(name="entity_id")
private BigInteger entityId;
}
```

Type A:

```
@Entity(name = "type_a")
@Transactional
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class TypeA extends AbstractType{
private String prop1;
private String prop2;
}
```

Type B:

```
@Entity(name = "type_b")
@Transactional
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class TypeB extends AbstractType{
private String prop3;
private String prop4;
}
```

I'm having a SQL error. The generated query tries to update the table of the abstract type (which shouldnt exist). This is part of the query:

```
update hibernate_sequences set sequence_next_hi_value = ? where 
sequence_next_hi_value = ? and sequence_name = 'abstract_type'
insert into type_a (some_prop, entity_id, prop1, prop2) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
insert into type_b (some_prop, entity_id, prop3, prop4) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
update abstract_type set entity_id=? where id=?
```

As you can see, it's trying to update a table which doesn't (and shouldnt) exist. 'abstract_type' table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3557879/2387977

Comment: If something is abstract, using @MappedSuperclass makes more sense. Inheritance is specified ONCE in the root class. You don't need to re-specify it in subclasses!

Comment: @Dherik, maybe is the same problem, but that solution didn't work for me. That approach doesn't save the FKs in the tables of the concrete classes.

Comment: @NeilStockton, I know I should use MappedSuperclass, but that doesn't work. Thats because my list is of that abstract type and it tries to find the abstract type entity and it doesn't exist if you use that annotation.

Comment: You mean "it doesn't work in Hibernate"? It does in other JPA implementations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873547/how-to-map-an-abstract-collection-with-jpa

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't name a class `Entity` without causing problems.

You can make this much simpler by minimizing the annotations and let JPA do it's work. A `Container` class holds a collection of `AbstractTypes`:

```
@Entity
public class Container {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AbstractType> types;

    public List<AbstractType> getTypes() { return types; }
    public void setTypes(List<AbstractType> types) { this.types = types; }
}
```

The `AbstractType` is just that:

```
@Entity
public abstract class AbstractType {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

And a couple concrete types to extend and inherit from the abstract superclass:
EDIT: A FK back to the `Container` class can be added with a ManyToOne association.

```
@Entity
public class TypeA extends AbstractType {
@ManyToOne
private Container container;

}
```

And:

```
@Entity
public class TypeB extends AbstractType {    
@ManyToOne
private Container container;
}
```

When I run this [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I get the following output:

```
Hibernate: create table AbstractType (DTYPE varchar(31) not null, id bigint not null, container_id bigint, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Container (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Container_AbstractType (Container_id bigint not null, types_id bigint not null)

Hibernate: insert into Container (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into AbstractType (container_id, DTYPE, id) values (?, 'TypeA', ?)
Hibernate: insert into AbstractType (container_id, DTYPE, id) values (?, 'TypeB', ?)
Hibernate: insert into Container_AbstractType (Container_id, types_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Container_AbstractType (Container_id, types_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select container0_.id as id1_1_ from Container container0_

model.Container@40591559
```

Comment: Naming a class Entity is really not a problem. Why should a JPA implementation prohibit that?!

Comment: Different question. "The import javax.persistence.Entity conflicts with a type defined in the same file"

Comment: The names of the class and properties are changed. "Entity" is not the name of my class...

Comment: I figured as much. Since it was causing compiler errors against the JPA spec, I figured I'd include it in the answer.

Comment: If I do what you are suggesting, I loose an important field which is the field of the FK on the TypeA and the TypeB. That is what's not working. If I take that out, it works. But I need this field.

Comment: Are you looking for a FK back to the `Container` class?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can't you add ManyToOne associations in concrete classes as per edits?

Comment: You only get "compiler errors" if you go off and do "import javax.persistence.Entity" in a class called Entity. Basic java FWIW!

Comment: Of course, and that's what I tried to do to annotate the original Entity Entity...